# How to modify application.conf during dist creation in Play Framework 2.3.x

Tags: jenkins, playframework, sbt

We use Jenkins to run builds for Play Framework 2.3.x project. This works fine and it creates a nice distribution packed in a zip file.

I would like that during the build to update one of the files in conf directory (for instance application.conf) and set the Jenkins build number/id in a variable so that I can always track the distribution file to the originating build.

I know it is possible to copy files to the distribution using "mappings in Universal" but I want to modify an existing file instead. This way I could then easily display the information on a page.

Comment: Did you look at following plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the plain old [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). With the [Unzip Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html) you can unzip the created zip file. Then you can use the [Replace Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) to replace a string in your application.conf. And at least the [Zip Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) to package your project again.

For a more Scala-ish way you could use [SBT Editsource](http://software.clapper.org/sbt-editsource/).

Comment: Thanks, akkie! I would like to stay with SBT and not resort to Ant. I did not know about SBT Editsource - it seems to address my issue. I will try it and report back.